# Reading Manipulating and Writing Data in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

If I have a column of values, how do I read the values into a variable in VBA, perform some operation on it and then write it to the next column? Seems mind numbingly simple but I haven't been able to find a simple guide.

for example:

Column A = 1, 4, 5, 7

without writing formulas into column B

Dim A, B

A = column a

B = log(A)

write the values of B to the next column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through a whole sheet you can do it like this.

```
Dim lRow as long
Dim strA as string
Dim strB as string

Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

lRow = 1
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

   'Read the data from columnA
   strA = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value

   'do something with the value you got from A
   strB  = strA & "some other text"
   strB = log(strA)

   'Write it to C
   ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = strB

   lRow = lRow + 1
   ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop
```

Or if you just want a certain predefined row it would be more hard coded like this.

```
'Read the data from columnA
strA = ws.Range("A6").Value

'do something with the value you got from A
strB  = strA & "some other text"
strB = log(strA)

'Write it to C
ws.Range("C6").Value = strB
```

Comment: nice thank you, did you expect `strA = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value` to work as is or do I need to specify values in that? (Got an error from that line)

Comment: That will load the value from cell A and whatever row your counter is on into the variable strA.  I wasn't sure what you were looking for exactly. Give me one minute and i'll add a look for that counter.

Comment: oh wow, so again, we're doing each value individually rather than grabbing the whole column, operating on it and then writing it to a column.

Comment: That is correct.  You could grab it by range but then I think you would have to iterate the range doing it to each cell in the range.

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro:

```
Sub test()
    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range
    Dim logCel As Double
    Dim lastRow As Integer

lastRow = Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)) 'Create a range to search

For Each cel In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then 'If the cell has a value in it
        logCel = Log(cel) 'add the LOG of the value to a variable
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = logCel 'In the cell to the right of the cell, put the log
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

To learn about setting cell values and such, I highly recommend using the macro recorder, then looking through the macro when you're done.  Start the recorder, then enter a value into a cell, then in the one next, enter a log of that one, and you'll get some idea of how VBA works.

Comment: So you have to iterate through each row as in your code? You can't move all the cell values into a data structure, do the operations and then write the data structure into a column?

Comment: What do you mean "into a data structure"?  You could add them to an array, do the math on the array, then return the results.  Do you need a "data structure" or just the log of the numbers (which the code gives you).  Note: You can also, naturally, write the Log answers into an array or some other thing, if necessary.

Comment: I'd rather not do all the operations in the worksheet. I can manipulate array's with vba, I just don't know how to get the data into and out of the array (to and from the worksheet). What commands do you use for this?

Comment: You should have mentioned those specifics in your OP - I thought you were just wondering how to set variables.  To use an Array, I suggest Googling around, as there are tons of sites to explain how to do so. [Here's one](http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm) and [another](http://excelmacromastery.com/Blog/?p=243) to get you going.

Comment: So you don't know how to write an array of data into consecutive cells of a column or define the values of an array using the values in consecutive cells of a column? Neither of those sources talk about that which has been my experience with other sources as well.

Comment: It's Item 12 in the second link @BruceWayne posted.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through cell by cell you would write directly to the worksheet using a `LOG` formula (no need for an array as the manipulation can be used directly with inserting a formula):

```
Sub LikeThis()
Dim rng1 As Range
`work on A1:A20 and write to B1:B20
Set rng1 = [a1:a20]
rng1.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>0,LOG(RC[-1]),""not valid"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. Somehow offset is consistently one of the most useful parts of vba.